# Continuity of right hand derivative of convex function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f$ is convex, then $\lim_{x \to a} f_{+}^{'}(x)=f_{+}^{'}(a)$ ?

Knowing that, for every convex function like $f$,and for every point like $a$, $f_{-}^{'}(a)$ and $f_{+}^{'}(a)$ exist, and $f_{-}^{'}(a) \le f_{+}^{'}(a)$ and $f_{-}^{'}(x)$ and $f_{+}^{'}(x)$ are increasing functions.

Proof needed please. Thanks.

Nomenclatures:

$f_{-}^{'}(a)=\lim_{x \to a^-} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$

$f_{+}^{'}(a)=\lim_{x \to a^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$.

I found out a proof, but I suspect that it's wrong at some points. help me correct it. my proof:

$A=\{f_{+}^{'}(x)\quad| \quad a<x\}$

$B=\{f_{+}^{'}(x)\quad|\quad x>a\}$

$A \neq \phi \quad \text{and for every }m,m \in A,\quad m>n,\quad n\in B\quad  \Rightarrow \quad A\quad \text{has infimum}.\quad I=INF(A).$

$\text{in the same way}\quad B \quad \text{has supremum}.\text{let }S=SUP(B).\quad \text{it is so easy to find out that}\quad S=I=f_{+}^{'}(a).$

$\text{for every }\epsilon>0,\quad \exists m\in A,\quad f_{+}^{'}(a)<m<f_{+}^{'}(a)+\epsilon.$

$ \quad  m=f_{+}^{'}(x_{m})$

$\quad  f_{+}^{'}(a)<f_{+}^{'}(x)<f_{+}^{'}(x_{m})<f_{+}^{'}(a)+\epsilon, \quad a<x<x_{m}$

$\Rightarrow Lim_{x\rightarrow a^{+}}f_{+}^{'}(x)=f_{+}^{'}(a).$

In the same way as above,$\quad Lim_{x\rightarrow a^{-}}f_{+}^{'}(x)=f_{+}^{'}(a).$

Answer (score 0):

$\text{It's quite possible that,}\quad S\ne f_{+}^{'}(a) \quad \text{and\or}\quad I\ne f_{+}^{'}(a).$ for example consider below function:

$f(x)=\Bigg \{ \begin{array}{cc} (x-1)^2-1 & x\le0\\ x^2 & x\ge 0 \end{array}$

$f(x)$ is convex but,

$Lim_{a\to0^- }f_{+}^{'}(x)=-2\ne Lim_{x\to0^+}f_{+}^{'}(x)=0.$